# Infinispan putAsync silent failures

Tags: infinispan

I am working on a project that uses Infinispan 11.0.15 as an embedded cache with clustering in REPL_ASYNC mode. I'm running with 2 cluster members, one of which I call "primary". The primary instance reads from a database and for each row, adds to the Infinispan cache using the putAsync method.

I have observed that intermittently, a small proportion of rows never make it into the cache. I have tracked all of the CompletableFutures and none of them wrap an exception. There are no key collisions. Essentially the call silently fails to ever insert the data into the cache.

I looked pretty carefully in the Infinispan Jira instance for anything which looked like it might relate to this behaviour but I have not found anything that looks similar. Is anyone aware of any issues that present like this? While upgrading the library is an option, without knowing whether this specific problem has been identified and fixed it's difficult to be certain if that's helped or not given the problem is intermittent and extremely difficult to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

`REPL_ASYNC` mode does not report any errors because the replication process happens in the background.

Quote from the [Documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#replicated-caches_clustered-caches)

```
Asynchronous replication is not recommended, because communication errors, or errors that happen on remote nodes are not reported to the caller.
```

I advise using `REPL_SYNC` instead.